# MERGE: INSERT on MATCH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am downloading data that will have duplicates with previously downloaded data.

I am successfully using a MERGE statement to throw away the duplicates based on transaction number.   Supposedly that is sufficient, but I would like to monitor if the detail ever changes on a particular transaction.

To that end I added a `when matched` clause on the `merge` with an additional insert that identifies the record as a duplicate.

This logic should not trigger very often so I am not too concerned that this method (if it worked) would report the same duplicate multiple times.

When I prepare this code I get this error message:

```
An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement.
```

Is there a way to get the duplicate record to insert into this table or another table using the MERGE statement?

I am open to other solutions, but I would really like to find a way to do this with the MERGE statement because it would impact my code the least.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.TransactionDetail as t
USING (SELECT @TransNr --bigint
             ,@Detail  -- [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
      ) as s
      ([TranNr]
      ,[Detail]
      )
   on t.TranNr = s.TranNr and t.CHANGED_RECORD = 0
 when not matched then
      INSERT (CHANGED_RECORD
         ,[TranNr]
             ,[Detail]
             )
      VALUES(0, s.TranNr, s.Detail)
/* Adding this does not allow statement to be prepared....
 when matched and s.Detail <> t.Detail
 then
      INSERT (CHANGED_RECORD
         ,[TranNr]
             ,[Detail]
             )
      VALUES(1, s.TranNr, s.Detail)
*/
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INSERT` statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TransactionDetail (CHANGED_RECORD,TranNr,Detail)
SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM dbo.TransactionDetail 
            WHERE TranNr=@TransNr AND CHANGED_RECORD=0 AND Detail<>@Detail
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CHANGED_RECORD,
        @TransNr AS TranNr, @Detail AS Detail
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TransactionDetail 
    WHERE TranNr=@TransNr AND CHANGED_RECORD=0 AND Detail=@Detail
)
```

This will skip inserting if a row which has `CHANGED_RECORD=0` has the same detail. However, if the same detail it's found in another row which has `CHANGED_RECORD=1`, a new duplicate would be inserted. To avoid that, remove the `AND CHANGED_RECORD=0` condition from the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` subquery.

You may also want to create a unique filtered index, to ensure unicity for the rows which have `CHANGED_RECORD=0`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_TransactionDetail_Filtered 
ON TransactionDetail (TranNr) /*INCLUDE (Detail)*/ WHERE CHANGED_RECORD=0
```

The `INCLUDE (Detail)` clause could also marginally improve performance of queries that are looking for the `Detail` of the rows which have `CHANGED_RECORD=0` (at the expense of some additional disk space and a small performance penalty when updating the `Detail` column of existing rows).

Comment: This is the first I have seen a filtered index.  That is awesome.  I can use that in many places.